# How To Format This Scraped Content

Tags: php, html, dom, scrape

I'm grabbing the content from all the td's in this table with the class="job" using this.

```
$table01 = $salary->find('table.table01');
$rows = $table01[0]->find('td.job');
```

Then I'm using this to output it which works, but obviously only outputs it as plaintext, I need to do some more with it...

```
foreach($table01[0]->find('td.job') as $element) {
$jobs .= $element->plaintext . '<br />';
}
```

Ultimately I would like it outputted to this format. Notice the a href is using the job name and replacing spaces and / with a -.

```
<tr>
  <td class="small"> <a href="/graphic-artist-designer">Graphic Artist / Designer</a>
    $23,755 – $55,335  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="small"> <a href="/sales-associate">Sales Associate</a><br />
    $15,577 – $56,290  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="small"> <a href="/film-video-editor">Film / Video Editor</a><br />
    $24,184 – $94,493  </td>
</tr>
```

Heres the table im scraping

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table01">

<tr>
    <td class="head">Test</td>
    <td class="job">
    <a href="/Graphic_Artist_%2f_Designer" id="UniqueID1">Graphic Artist / Designer</a><br/>
    $23,755 – $55,335
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td class="head">Test</td>
    <td class="job">
    <a href="/Sales_Associate" id="UniqueID2">Sales Associate</a><br/>
    $15,577 – $56,290
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td class="head">Test</td>
    <td class="job">
    <a href="/Film_%2f_Video_Editor" id="UniqueID3">Film / Video Editor</a><br/>
    $24,184 – $94,493
    </td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

may be better to use regexps

```
<?php
$html=file_get_contents('1.html');
$jobs='';
if(preg_match_all("/<tr>.*?<td.*?>.*?<\/td>.*?<td\sclass=\"job\">.*?<a.+?href=\"(.+?)\".+?>(.*?)<\/a>(.*?)<\/td>.*?<\/tr>/ims", $html, $res))
{
  foreach($res[1] as $i=>$uri)
  {
    $uri=strtolower(urldecode($uri));
    $uri=preg_replace("/_\/_/",'-',$uri);
    $uri=preg_replace("/_/",'-',$uri);
    $jobs.='<tr><td class="small"> <a href="'.$uri.'">'.$res[2][$i].'</a>'.$res[3][$i].'</td></tr>'."\n";
  }
}
echo $jobs;
```